# Problem with input type="file" in Mozilla web extension

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm porting extension from Chrome to Firefox.

Have an html with

```
<input type="file" id="protocol-file"/>
```

After pressing an extension button I see my input. Then start to select local file from disk - I see window with file list on my disk, but extension windows dissapeared (only in Firefox, in Chrome it still remains visible).

I tried to add

```
document.getElementById('protocol-file').onchange = function() {
    alert('protocol-file changed');
};
```

but it doesn't work - I don't see alert after file selected.

It seems that extension finishes working on selecting files in Firefox. In Chrome everything is Ok.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="file-input-block">
            <span class="file-label">Файл:</span>
            <input type="file" id="protocol-file"/>
       </div>    
    </div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    document.getElementById('protocol-file').onchange = function() {
        alert('protocol-file changed');
    };
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Example",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Mozilla ext example",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "notifications",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Example file select",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "my@examle.com",
      "strict_min_version": "49.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: @Makyen, have done

Comment: have you found anything @NatalyaMamayeva ?? I'm facing the same problem, on chrome it works just fine, it prevents the extension from closing but firefox moves focus on the select file window and that closes the extension. If you have the "Prevent extension from closing" options from the extension console active, it doesn't close, so I have narrowed it down to an issue of focus so far.